# Vitest is failing to resolve import of file that uses redux even when the function I'm testing doesn't have anything to do with redux

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit, vitest

## Problem description

I have a Next.js (Typescript) project that uses redux and Vitest. The redux slices work without any issues (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript) and Vitest also works perfectly for functions defined within files that don't use any Redux-related hook.

Nonetheless, when I add a test to a function located in a file that uses redux, Vitest will throw a "Failed to resolve import.....Does the file exist?" error, even when I try to test a function that don't have anything to do with the component nor redux.

Here is how I isolated the issue (I'm using ***In-source testing***, but also tried placing the test in an independent foo.test.ts file with the same result):

### DummyComponent.tsx

```tsx
import { useAppDispatch } from 'store/hooks'
import { someAction } from 'store/some-slice/action

export default function DummyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  const dummyAction = () => {
    dispatch(someAction())
  }
  return <button onClick={dummyAction}>Run action</button>;
}


// ↓↓↓ Function that will be tested ↓↓↓
function hasNothingToDoWithRedux(a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b;
}

if (import.meta.vitest) {
  const { describe, expect, it } = import.meta.vitest;
  describe("Testing hasNothingToDoWithRedux", () => {
    it("Sums two values correctly", () => {
      const a = 2;
      const b = 1;
      expect(hasNothingToDoWithRedux(a, b)).toBe(3);
    });
  });
}
```

When running `yarn vitest`, it will throw the "Error: Failed to resolve import.....Does the file exist?"

**If I comment out `dispatch(someAction())`, the error will go away, the test will be run and pass, which makes me think it has something to do with how Vitest is being configured, but I have no idea what is happening ‍♂️**

### vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";

export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    "import.meta.vitest": "undefined",
  },
  test: {
    includeSource: ["./**/*.{js,ts,tsx}"],
  },
});
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["vitest/importMeta"]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "shift-management",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "vitest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "luxon": "^3.0.4",
    "next": "13.0.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "sass": "^1.55.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/luxon": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.8",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.25.3",
    "eslint": "8.25.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
    "vite": "^3.2.4",
    "vitest": "^0.25.3"
  }
}
```

## Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into something similar. In my search for an answer, I ran [across this thread](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/3287#issuecomment-1534645169), and adding the tldr here.

Its possible `vitest` can't find the redux import due to [dual package hazard](https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.7.0/docs/api/esm.html#esm_dual_package_hazard). Something like this might help in your `test:` config inside of `vite.config.js`

```
   alias: [
      {
        find: "react-redux/es/exports",
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react-redux/lib/exports"),
      },
    ],
```

ymmv, as the paths might vary in your local env, but perhaps this might offer some clues to unblock you and/or future travelers